# Does nothing get called after dispatch in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, redux

I am trying to map over an array and call dispatch every time. it's working in the code but failing in unit tests. see below

```
const errorArray = [this contains 2 objects]

errorArray.map(err => dispatch(myFunc(MY_VAR, err.msg)))
```

when I then assert `expect(myFunc).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)` it fails because it says it was only called once

so then I changed my code to be

```
console.log('hi')
dispatch(myFunc(MY_VAR, 'randomstring'))
```

// this printed out 'hi'

I then swapped it round to be

```
dispatch(myFunc(MY_VAR, 'randomstring'))
console.log('hi')
```

and hi was NOT logged. does this mean that once dispatch has happened, nothing else gets called after? this would also explain the first part when I'm asserting for 2 dispatches. but it's only doing the first one. what am i doing wrong? I just want to map over my errors array and dispatch for every one inside there

Answer (score 0):

Mapping over an array returns a new array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

A for-loop seems to be the better construct:

`errorArray.forEach(function(element) {
  dispatch(myFunc(MY_VAR, element.msg))
});`

Comment: nah, that makes no difference :/

Comment: Can you set up a Stackblitz or Plunkr, so we get a better idea of the problem?